# How do I make Docker 'type'?

Tags: docker

I am installing composer (a PHP tool) in my docker container, and at some point the installation script asks for a Y/N option:

```
We are about to initialize the the application. Proceed ? [Y/n]
```

How do I make Dockerfile predict it and answer it in time?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @EvanCarslake I am trying to make docker, in an automated way, select 'Y' when the installation script asks for an input

Comment: Isn't there an option (like a flag --non-interactive) for the installation which just skips this interaction? E.g. For `apt-get install` you can add the flag `-y` to make it non interactive.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo your selection and pipe it to your scripts, assume you need answer Yes, Yes, No to your script, you can do like this: `echo "Y Y N" | php composer.phar install` or if you want all `yes` or all `no`, you can just use [yes](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) to do it with `yes y | php composer.phar install` or `yes n | php composer.phar.install`